# Redux store updating but mapStateToProps not updating component props

Tags: react-redux, react-google-maps

When I click on a pointer on my Google Maps component, I can see my store being updated in Redux Devtools but `mapStateToProps` does not seem to update my component props. Therefore, my Google Maps pointers `<InfoWindow>` does not open.

If I navigate to another Link(using react-router) from my NavBar and then navigate back to this page, the component receives the updated props from `mapStateToProps` and the previously clicked Google Maps pointer has the `<InfoWindow>` open.

I have been trying to debug this for the past 1 week, tried converting `components/ClassSchedule/Map/Pure.jsx` to a class component but it did not work.

components/ClassSchedule/Map/index.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectClass } from '../../../actions/index';
import Pure from './Pure';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  selectedClass: state.classMapTable.selectedClass,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  selectClass: id => dispatch(selectClass(id)),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Pure);
```

components/ClassSchedule/Map/Pure.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import MapContent from './MapContent';

const Map = props => {
  return (
    <MapContent
      googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=googleMapsKeyHere`}
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      containerElement={<div style={{ height: `550px` }} />}
      mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

export default Map;
```

components/ClassSchedule/Map/MapContent.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,
} from 'react-google-maps';

import { defaultPosition } from '../../../data/mapData';
import { classes } from '../../../data/classData';
const { zoom, centre } = defaultPosition;

const MapContent = withScriptjs(
  withGoogleMap(({ selectedClass, selectClass }) => (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={zoom} defaultCenter={centre}>
      {classes.map(c => (
        <Marker
          key={`map${c.id}`}
          icon={
            'https://mt.google.com/vt/icon?psize=30&font=fonts/arialuni_t.ttf&color=ff304C13&name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-a.png&ax=43&ay=48&text=%E2%80%A2'
          }
          position={c.coordinates}
          onClick={() => selectClass(c.id)}
        >
          {selectedClass === c.id && (
            <InfoWindow>
              <React.Fragment>
                <div>{c.area}</div>
                <div>{`${c.level} ${c.subject}`}</div>
                <div>{`${c.day}, ${c.time}`}</div>
              </React.Fragment>
            </InfoWindow>
          )}
        </Marker>
      ))}
    </GoogleMap>
  ))
);

export default MapContent;
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import classMapTable from './classMapTable';

export default history =>
  combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    classMapTable,
  });
```

reducers/classMapTable.js

```
const classMapTable = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SELECT_CLASS':
      return { ...state, selectedClass: action.classId };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default classMapTable;
```

store/index.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import createRootReducer from '../reducers';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  const store = createStore(
    createRootReducer(history),
    preloadedState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history)))
  );
  return store;
}
```

actions/index.js

```
export const selectClass = classId => ({
  type: 'SELECT_CLASS',
  classId,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After debugging for about 2 weeks, I randomly decided to run `npm update`. Turns out there wasn't any issue with my code, my npm packages were just outdated/not compatible. I have no idea how I had different versions of react and react-dom. EVERYTHING WORKS NOW.

This was in my package.json:

```
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-dev-utils": "^7.0.0",
"react-dom": "^16.4.2",
```

After updating my package.json:

```
"react": "^16.8.1",
"react-dev-utils": "^7.0.1",
"react-dom": "^16.8.1",
```

Moral of the story: KEEP YOUR PACKAGES UP TO DATE.